# Jerky movement in WPF

Tags: c#, key, keypress

I've got a canvas that's 800x600 inside a window that's 300x300. When I press a certain key, I want it the canvas to move in that direction.
I've done this inside the window's code behind:

```
protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnKeyDown(e);
    Key keyPressed = e.Key;

    if (keyPressed == Key.W)
    {
        gcY += 5;
    }
    if (keyPressed == Key.S)
    {
        gcY -= 5;
    }
    if (keyPressed == Key.A)
    {
        gcX += 5;
    }
    if (keyPressed == Key.D)
    {
        gcX -= 5;
    }

    gameCanvas.RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform(gcX, gcY);
}
```

Well, it works, but the movement is jerky. And if I hold on to a key, <kbd>W</kbd> for instance, then it pauses for a split second, before moving.
Is there anyway to make the movement smoother and to get rid of the pause when you hold down a key?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, your setup is accepting spammed keyinput (holding down a key). The way I've seen it done in most games with event based input is to use a boolean array, `keydown[256]`, mapping the keyboard (the index being the key value); all values initialized to `false`.

When the key is pressed, you set the the appropriate index to `true` in the keydown method and in your game/rendering loop, you call `gameCanvas.RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform(gcX, gcY);` depending on what keys in the array are `true`. You set the key value to `false` when the key is released in the keyrelease event method (I'm not sure what it is in C#).

This way you will get smooth scrolling and it wont have a delay in starting up.

Comment: Hey, thanks. But do you know why that works and the way that I had it before doesn't?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could incorporate the time into your calculation. Currently you add/substract 5 whenever the event fires, and that's not really predictable.

To smoothe the movement make sure you don't fire more often than X times per second by using a DateTime.

like:

```
private static DateTime nextUpdate

if (nextUpdate <= DateTime.Now)
{
//Move
nextUpdate = DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(100);
}
```

I don't have VS right now, so I'm not perfectly sure for the syntax, but you get the idea.